# C/C++ Linux: fastest write of a fixed chunk of memory to file (1 Hz)

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory, io

On a Linux system, I have one 7MB chunk of memory of fixed size (no growth) whose contents I refresh in a real-time application.

I need to write this chunk of memory to disk (same file) once per second.

Taking into consideration modern (late 2011) CPUs and HDDs, what is the most efficient way to implement this functionality?  I don't care if the write actually takes some time, but as this is a real-time app, I need to return to the running app ASAP.

What methodologies should I be trying?

My baseline is a standard baseline fopen(), binary fwrite(), fclose() cycle.

I have read that mmap() might be useful.  Maybe asynchronous I/O?  Are there other methodologies that I should be benchmarking?  Off the top of your head, which methodology do you think would be fastest?

Comment: If you don't care how long it takes to do the actual write, then the modern approach is to just hand it off to a thread to do.

Comment: Async IO could be the fastest

Comment: ty Nicol - a writer thread seems to be the easiest to implement given the code I have in place.  I will try this out against mmap.

Comment: A good answer depends on whether you want the state of the file to be consistent, can accept to sometimes miss the write, or are on a realtime OS. e.g. when you need consistent images, copy the 7MB into a secondary buffer and hand the writing of to another thread. that way you wont get interrupted in your normal flow. only do the copy/handoff when there is no write to disk running.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`mmap(2)` is the way to go. Just call `msync(2)` with `MS_ASYNC` when you want to write it.

Comment: Can you cite a source for this? Why is `mmap` the fastest?

Comment: @spraff: It directly frobs the memory in the cache, instead of spending time copying chunks of memory as per `fread(3)`/`fwrite(3)`.

Comment: Ignacio, ty for your suggestion - I am trying out the example in Stevens atm.  BTW, my chunk happens to have a complex data structure, but it really is one chunk (eg no std::string).  Using standard binary I/O, there is a lot of coding for individual PODs.  I suspect that I don't need any of this for mmap - is this correct?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams IIUC, his problem isn't the actual type to write the data, but the time the write will block his application.  In this case, `msync` is best called from a separate thread.

Comment: @James: What for? `MS_ASYNC` will cause it to return immediately.

Comment: ty, Ignacio - it was easier to implement than I expected and my test ran SO FAST that it it making me rethink my entire application design.  I currently have threads that write to MySQL (extremely slow) - I am tempted to break my app into two parts - the main realtime daemon to do work and just write mmap files and a second daemon to read from those files (listen for changes somehow - like the way tail -f works) and write to Mysql as a second process.  thx again for your guidance!

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes, but the second thread can more easily manage the periodic repetitions.  And even a system call which returns immediately takes more time than no system call at all:-).

Comment: hahaha - I had to look up "frob" - which redirected me to frobnicate (v.v.nice):  [Poss. derived from frobnitz, and usually abbreviated to frob, but frobnicate is recognized as the official full form.:] To manipulate or adjust, to tweak. One frequently frobs bits or other 2-state devices. Thus: “Please frob the light switch” (that is, flip it), but also “Stop frobbing that clasp; you'll break it”. One also sees the construction to frob a frob. See tweak and twiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I'd combine the two approaches mentionned: I'd use `mmap` to map the
memory to the file, then set up a separate thread (with lower priority)
to `msync` it every second.  (In this case, the actual arguments to
`msync` are not too important; you don't need `MS_ASYNC`, since you
won't be blocking the main thread.)

Another alternative possibly worth trying would be asynchronous IO.
It's not clear to me from my documentation what happens if you never
recover the results, however, so you may need some sort of reaper code
to prevent lost resources.  (Asynchronous IO seems rather underspecified
in Posix, which IMHO is a good reason to avoid it.)